How can I set the Bearer Token just before making a request using Apache Http Client 4
I still use Apache Http Client 4.
But, I would like to set the Bearer Token just before making a request.
Then, I have tried the following
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try (CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.custom().setMaxConnTotal(2)
                .addInterceptorFirst(new Interceptor()).build()) {
            httpclient.start();
            final CountDownLatch latchComplete = new CountDownLatch(10);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("https://www.google.com"), new CallBack(latchComplete));
            }
            latchComplete.await();
        } catch (final IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class CallBack implements FutureCallback<HttpResponse> {
        CountDownLatch latchComplete;

        CallBack(final CountDownLatch pCountDownLatch) {
            this.latchComplete = pCountDownLatch;
        }

        @Override
        public void completed(final HttpResponse pHttpResponse) {
            this.latchComplete.countDown();
            System.out.println("completed");
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(final Exception pE) {
            this.latchComplete.countDown();
            System.out.println("failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled() {
            this.latchComplete.countDown();
            System.out.println("cancelled");
        }
    }

    static class Interceptor implements HttpRequestInterceptor {
        @Override
        public void process(final HttpRequest pHttpRequest, final HttpContext pHttpContext)
                throws HttpException, IOException {
            System.out.println("Interceptor");
        }
    }
}


I exected the output on console the following.
Interceptor
Interceptor
completed
completed
Interceptor
completed
Interceptor
completed
Interceptor
completed
Interceptor
completed
Interceptor
completed
Interceptor
completed
Interceptor
completed
Interceptor
completed

However, when I actually execute it, it displayed the following
Interceptor
Interceptor
Interceptor
Interceptor
Interceptor
Interceptor
Interceptor
Interceptor
Interceptor
Interceptor
completed
completed
completed
completed
completed
completed
completed
completed
completed
completed

This means that the HttpRequestInterceptor has been executed when the first for statement is executed.
If I use this process to handle registering tokens in the header, but make a lot of requests, I can expect our tokens to expire while I am making those requests.
The RequestInterceptor in httpclient5 seems to work as I expect, but is there any way to achieve this behavior in httpclient4?

Example request from client has:
Authorization: Bearer eyITVC...h7HgQ

Auto configuration
private static class Interceptor implements HttpRequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void process(final HttpRequest httpRequest, final HttpContext httpContext)
            throws HttpException, IOException {
        ServletRequestAttributes servletRequestAttributes
                = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

        String authHeader = servletRequestAttributes.getRequest().getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        log.info("Header: {}", authHeader); // Bearer eyITVC...h7HgQ
        if (StringUtils.hasText(authHeader)) {
            httpRequest.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
        }
    }
}

If you want to add manually
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com");
    httpGet.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + Your_JWT);
    // Call request
} catch (UnsupportedOperationException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

For async request
AsyncRequestProducer producer = AsyncRequestBuilder
            .get("https://www.google.com")
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + Your_JWT)
            .build();

httpClient.execute(producer, ...);


Thank you for your answer.It looks good when I am trying to process with synchronous execution. May I ask how to do this asynchronously?

@SuzukiYuu See updated.

Tahnk you. I will try it.
